# How to build a fault-tolerant app in Storm?

Tags: distributed-computing, apache-storm

The short version of the question: how to build a fail-safe word count program (topology) in Twitter Storm that produces **accurate** results even when failure occurs? Is that even possible?

Long version: I am studying Twitter Storm and trying to understand how it should be used. I have followed the [tutorial](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Tutorial) and find it a very simple concept. But the word count example outlined in the tutorial is not fault tolerant (because *bolts* save some data in memory). Saving the same data in back-end DB however leads to double counting if an event is re-submitted to the start of chain (which happens when some of the *bolts* fail).

Should I see Twitter Storm as real-time platform for producing **partially accurate** results and still depend on MapReduce to get the accurate ones?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what kind of failure your trying to hege against. There are a few things that you can do:

1. Storm bolts are supposed to ack a tuple only after they have processed it. If you write your spouts and bolts and topology to use this, you can implement an "exactly one time" system which will guarantee accuracy.
2. Kafka can be a good way to put data into Storm because it uses disk persistance to keep messages  around for a long time even after they are consumed. This means you can retrieve them if there's a failure by a consumer down the line.

In general though, it's difficult to guarantee that things are processed exactly once in any streaming system. This is a known problem, and it is a very difficult problem to solve efficiently.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a bit. About the first option... can I "split" tuple in spout so that different (independent) calculation paths are handled in parallel? (so that if one of them fails the others are not replayed, just the offending one?) In general, I would like to know how to build a system that would always yield accurate results (or at least know they are not accurate). I am talking about counting statistics, nothing too complex.

Answer (score 0):

Storm has the concept of transactional topologies.  In practice, this means you will want to process items in batches, then commit to your database at the end of the batch, storing the transaction ID in the database alongside a count.  This also has the practical benefit of reducing the load on your database with fewer inserts.

Batches are processed in parallel and may be replayed on failure, but are guaranteed to be committed in order.  This is important because it makes it safe to write code that fetches the current count row, checks the transaction ID against the one in memory, and if the two differ (meaning it is an uncommitted batch), adding the new count to the existing one and committing that updated count.

See the following link for much more information and code examples:

https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Transactional-topologies